# Do UIEvent and UIEventTypeMotion intercept shaking gesture only ?

Tags: ios, motion-detection, uievent

Reading [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html)i found that UIEventTypeMotion is useful only to intercept Shake. It sounds weird... but the only subtype on a `UIEventTypeMotion` is `UIEventTypeMotionShake`. 
I can't understand how to use function `- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in other way..

Comment: yep, at the moment the only motion gesture it recognises is shaking

Comment: I know, this is a terrible short question... and the only possible answer would be a short one :P but could you kindly add answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, at the moment the only motion gesture it recognises is shaking. by the looks of it apple will probably be adding more in the future, but we'll have to wait and see :)

Comment: still waiting for apple :(